# Changing the product position in a category programatically

Tags: magento-1.8, position

|I have this script that I want to use to change the product position in a category programatically  but I want like it to get SKUs from a csv

```
<?php
 require_once './app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
umask(0);



$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); //get an instance of the core resource
$connection = $resource->getConnection('core_write'); //get an instance of the write connection

$tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog/category_product'); //this should add the prefix if you have one

$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$io->streamOpen('./var/import/importpositions.csv', 'r+');
//$file = fopen('./var/import/importCats.csv', 'r');
while($csvData = $io->streamReadCsv()){
    if (isset($csvData[0])){ //get the first column - sku
         $sku = trim($csvData[0]);
         //get id by sku
         $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku); //get the product id.
         $sql = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET `position` = 0 WHERE `product_id` = {$id}"; //set the position to 0 for the product in all the categories.
         $connection->query($q); //run the query

    }
}
$io->streamClose();
?>
```

How to I set it to get a list of SKus in a CSV

I get this error when I run the script

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('', Array) #5 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('', Array) #6 /var/www/html/importposition.php(24): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(NULL) #7 {main} Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/D in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234
```

Comment: it is not that the product does not exists so no id is being returned? Feel free to show use what print_r($sql); actually shows

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can read a csv.
Let's assume the file has only one column with the sku.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
umask(0);



$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); //get an instance of the core resource
$connection = $resource->getConnection('core_write'); //get an instance of the write connection

$tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog/category_product'); //this should add the prefix if you have one

$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$io->streamOpen('path/to/file.csv', 'r+');
while($csvData = $io->streamReadCsv()){
    if (isset($csvData[0])){ //get the first column - sku
         $sku = trim($csvData[0]);
         //get id by sku
         $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku); //get the product id.
         $sql = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET `position` = 0 WHERE `product_id` = {$id}"; //set the position to 0 for the product in all the categories.
         $connection->query($sql); //run the query

    }
}
$io->streamClose();
```

If you want to upload the file and not read it from the disk just create a simple html form with a file input

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

And replace in the code above

```
$io->streamOpen('path/to/file.csv', 'r+');
```

with

```
$io->streamOpen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r+');
```

Comment: I have tried to execute the script but it returns a blank page.

Comment: This is what I am currently using

Comment: @Stifboy I didn't test the code. Maybe I forgot a semicolon or something like that. add this at the top of the file to see the errors `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I get some errors. Have posted above the error I get

Comment: @Stifboy. Try it now. the query string variable was named `$sql` but the call was made with the var name `$q` that doesn't exist.

Comment: http://magento.australianfavors.com.au/importposition.php  Still the same

Comment: How to save product position for a particular category?